# JQuery character counter with multiple inputs

Tags: jquery, count, char

I found the solution below to a simple textbox character counter (like Twitter).

Rather than use a single textbox, I've been trying to amend the code to accommodate multiple  text inputs without success.

The reason is because I want to validate a URL and text before sending them as the same tweet.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

```
<span class="counter"></span>
<input type="text" name="field1" id="field1" class="word_count" />
<input type="text" name="field2" id="field2" class="word_count" />
```

**js:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.word_count').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var counter = $this.parent().find('.counter');
        var maxlength = $this.attr('maxlength');

        counter.text('Only ' + maxlength + ' characters allowed');

        $this.bind('input keyup keydown', function () {
            var value = $this.val();

            if (value.length > 0) {
                counter.text((maxlength - $this.val().length) + ' characters left');
            } else {
                counter.text('Only ' + maxlength + ' characters allowed');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all here's the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/bczengel/tsbfU/

Here were the issues.

1. The code is looking for a maxLength attribute on the input fields that was not present. Hence the NaN messages.
2. If your using the latest version of jQuery you should be using the .on() method. It has a few other features over bind but basically its the newer method.
3. You don't need to iterate over all of the inputs. jQuery will bind your events to all elements it finds in its result set. Basically you were creating a new function for each input when only one was necessary.
4. I added focus to the list of events so that the counter was updated when you entered an input. You may want to add a separate blur event handler to hide the counter when no input is focused.

Comment: Thanks Brian - that's brilliant. Although I was hoping to have a single counter that totals the characters for all text inputs. So for example, I have 140 characters to use in both inputs.

Comment: Okay, so... I've tried to integrate Brian's solution with code that sets default input text values. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nBYLP/56/ What I need is to figure out how to make the character count ignore the input values if they are set to the default (as you see, it doesn't quite behave as it should). What might make this simpler is if all text boxes cleared when just one of them is focused and then all are repopulated when all contain no values. Can this be achieved without majorly modifying the existing code?

Comment: Surprisingly, I think I've managed to resolve this myself. :) (Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nBYLP/66/) just by creating the variable $content = $('.content'); and focusing/blurring on $content rather than $element. Is that really all that was required? It seems too easy...

Comment: I was right. It was too easy. :( This works as it should except for the blur event. If one of the fields contains an inputted value, the other field should remain empty on blur. But right now, it reverts to the default value.

Comment: Have you considered using a polyfill to implement the HTML5 placeholder attribute in older browsers? A polyfill is javascript that implements a feature to spec using javascript if the browser doesn't natively support it.  In this case I'm using webshims.lib which leaves an entire collection of polyfills at your disposal. http://jsfiddle.net/bczengel/tsbfU/10/

Comment: Here is the link for webshims.lib. http://afarkas.github.com/webshim/demos/ It requires modernizr and jquery

Comment: Ahhh - I wasn't aware of the placeholder attribute. That's a much more elegant solution. Thanks for the webshim link too - I'll look into that for sure. The only other thing I'd like to do is pass text from a list to the input values. Is there an "event" I can add to the .on function that calls the word count? Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tsbfU/43/

Comment: You just needed to move the event binding into your ready function. Basically it was running before the "Agree" link existed. Also, when setting/getting values from a form input use the `.val()` method. http://jsfiddle.net/bczengel/tsbfU/47/

Comment: Gotcha. :) All sorted. Thanks for everything Brian